# SSRS Serial Numbering a static row within a group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, report

I created a group within a table on SSRS

I used < =rownumber(nothing) > to auto serial the detailed row

the problem is that I need to generate another auto serial for the static row within the group to start from 1 and increasing by 1 according this static row only

I tried using code.

```
Public rn as Integer

Public Function GetRn() AS Integer
    rn = rn +1
    return rn
End Function
```

It worked fine, but it starts from 1 for each new page of the report

I also notice it started from 433 if it's printed as pdf or exported as pdf.

find the attached pic

[image]

[the required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IssWC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add an expression to the textbook.

`=RowNumber("YourRowGroupNameHere")`

Comment: I tried this, but it generates the counting of the group records

Comment: I also tried the same formula with "nothing", it generates the number of last record for each group records, which works fine as a serial for all table records

Comment: Can you post the expected results?

Comment: thanks for reply, kindly find the required result on the attached pic at the last of the post.